# mc открывет разные zip арохивы по-разному

Tags: linux, zip, fedora, mc

Не так давно заметил странность. mc открывает одни zip архивы в панели, другие — через ГУИ

Речь одет о *.zip файлах, и ни о каких-то других. Именно так. Расширение в нижнем регистре.

```
]$ file metal.zip 
metal.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
]$ xdg-mime query filetype metal.zip 
application/zip
```

Вот этот раскрывает через ГУИ, но

```
]$ xdg-mime query filetype layer_painter-main.zip 
application/zip
]$ file layer_painter-main.zip 
layer_painter-main.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

В панели, как и нужно. Unzip установлен. Думал, не может открыть архив, но файлы внутри видит.

```
]$ unzip -l metal.zip 
Archive:  metal.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
   246494  10-12-2021 18:26   albedo.png
     3129  10-12-2021 18:26   height.png
   106072  10-12-2021 18:26   metalness.png
   296716  10-12-2021 18:26   normal.png
   257018  10-12-2021 18:26   roughness.png
---------                     -------
   909429                     5 files
```

В чём может быть причина такого странного поведения. Попадаются и такие и такие архивы. "Правильных" раза в два больше, но есть такие, которые никак не хотят открыться в панели.

Удалось отследить "виновника". Если в архиве есть картинка, он открывает через ГУИ

Comment: Я перестал пользоваться mc как тяжёлым наследием DOSа примерно с десять лет назад, и ни разу не пожалел. Командная строка в *nix системах гораздо эффективнее в использовании.

Comment: А к вопросу, я бы смотрел имена файлов и размеры, да и 7z лучше запускать, а не всякое старьё. У mc есть скрипт-обёртка, который смотрит в архивы, отлаживайте его.

Comment: `mc` использует перловый скрипт `/usr/lib/mc/extfs.d/uzip`. Добавьте в него отладочную печать.

Comment: @0andriy, а где лежат настройки mc, чтобы заставить его распаковывать zip с помощью 7z?

Comment: @0andriy, вы полагаете, что нажать Ф5 сложнее, чем набирать cp ....... и длинный путь где запросто ошибиться?

Comment: F5, потом что-то ещё, это как мышкой в Shell работать, ага. Попробуйте использовать всю мощь *nix систем, не тратьте зря своё время.

Comment: Настройки лежат я полагаю в mime-types, а сам mc может что-то и делает в этом случае, тогда как выше заметили, надо в скрипт смотреть, ещё была системная конфигурация либо в /usr/share/mc, либо в /usr/lib/mc.

Comment: @0andriy, ну просветите меня, почему набор длинных путей будет быстрее, чем горячие клавиши в mc?

Comment: Да ну, вам ещё может документацию о completions вслух почитать? Я считаю, что тема себя исчерпала, не хотите — не стоит себя мучать, мудрость приходит с возрастом ;)

Comment: MC -   наследие DOS? Интересно откуда в DOS был MC.

Comment: @xmikex FAR, NC рожденные досом. МЦ не обязательно быть в ДОСе чтоб быть его наследием.

Comment: @0andriy  на десктопе тоже уже не пользуюсь, но на сервера ставлю с единственной целью - выбрать один файл в архиве чтоб распаковать в нужную папку)

Comment: eri, из-за того, что в MC интерфейс схожий с NC он становится наследием DOS? Странноватая логика, если честно.

Comment: @eri, ну это же делается с помощью командной строки и completions. `tar`, `7z`, ... умеют это из коробки. Completions в bash ставятся отдельным пакетом, а в zsh — одна из старейших его фич.